# make UIlabel present '...'

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want `UIlabel` to truncate text and present `...` at the end.
Is there an automatic way to do that?
(I was under the impression that it happens automatically like in `UIButton` but it doesn't)

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode): *NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
The line is displayed so that the beginning fits in the container and the missing text at the end of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph.* Don't be lazy.

Comment: @duci9y - today I learnt a new word ellipsis (non native english speaker... sorry... :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens automatically if `lineBreakMode` is set properly and the text contained by your label is too long to fit in the label's frame.

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

If you're using Interface Builder, you need to setup your label like this in the Inspector pane:

[image]